# drupal 7: create a list of ajax submit inside another ajax submit callback function

Tags: ajax

I have one ajax submit with its callback function, I need when I click on this submit add a list of submits with its ajax callback

My code in my module is:

```
function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['maindiv'] = array(
'#type' => 'container',
'#id' => 'maindiv',
'#attributes' => array(
  'class' => array('maindiv')
  ),
);


$form['maindiv']['submit1'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#id' => 'submit1',
      '#value' => t('create'),
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('submit1')
      ),
      '#executes_submit_callback' => true,
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'submit1_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'maindiv',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );

return $form;

}

function submit1_callback($form, $form_state) {

$form['maindiv']['listsubmit'] = array(
'#type' => 'container',
'#id' => 'listsubmit',
'#attributes' => array(
  'class' => array('listsubmit')
  ),
);

for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
{
    $form['maindiv']['listsubmit']['deletesubmit_'.$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#id' => 'deletesubmit_'.$i,
      '#value' => t('delete'),
      '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('deletesubmit')
      ),
      '#executes_submit_callback' => true,
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'deletesubmit_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'listsubmit',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );
}

return $form['maindiv'];
}

function deletesubmit_callback($form, $form_state) {

 //any code


return $form['maindiv'];
}
```

first submit work good , but whos created inside this submit callback function never apply ajax action, its referech the page without apply any thing .. what's wrong in my code?

thank you

Comment: Hi! Check this post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/149783/ajax-in-a-form-produces-an-error/149790

Comment: thank you Beebee for your reply, but I can't understand the point, its seems apply one callback of one submit, what I need inside that callback create a new submit have a new callback .. thank you

Comment: "what's wrong in my code?" was your question. Your code is fundamentally flawed that it will never work without the modifications suggested in the article above. You need to move all the `$form` modification into the form function. If you can't understand then sorry can't help you more.